# In Chef, how to read an attribute from environment file to chef recipe?

Tags: chef-infra, cookbook, recipe

I am downloading files from s3 bucket to aws instance with chef recipe,
now my bucket name changes with the environment like dev, qa and prod.

I'm using command like this but its not working, can anyone help?

```rb
execute "Downloading files from S3" do
  command "aws s3 sync s3://node['Bucket']/ /prod/users/myfiles/"
  cwd "/prod/"
  action :run
end
```

I tried `s3://#{node['Bucket']}/`, but it didn't work.

Chef environment file:

```json
"default_attributes": {
        "Bucket": "s3://mybucket"
}
```

Comment: you have duplication of `s3://` -- one in the string itself and the other in the Bucket attribute value. maybe this is all your pain...

Answer (score 0):

If that is really what you have in your environment, `node['Bucket']` is correct. You do need the `#{}` since you are interpolating in a string, so `command "aws s3 sync s3://#{node['Bucket']}/ /prod/users/myfiles/"`

Comment: I already tried `s3://#{node['Bucket']}/ ` it didnt worked, i mentioned that also

Comment: Like I said, it depends on what your env actually contains. Run `knife environment show` or similar to check what Chef Server thinks the env looks like.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
command "aws s3 sync s3://" + node['Bucket'] + "/ /prod/users/myfiles/"
```